# Every url in a django app only renders home.html

Tags: python, django, web, backend

So, I am not really lucky with latest django version tutorials, so I've had some problems with things that changed between some versions. One of this things is: althought I do exactly as I read/watch in the tutorials I always get the same result - all urls redirect to the same HTML page.

Here is my root urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('theblog.urls')),
]
```

Here is my app urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from .views import HomeView, ArticleDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    url('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    url('^article/<int:pk>', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),
]
```

For example, when I go to localhost:8000/articles/1 (or any other pk), it renders home.html (HomeView class) as if it was localhost:8000/.

Hope you can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things wrong with your code.

```
url('^article/<int:pk>', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),
```

This will not work. If you want to use [`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.url). you can't use `<int:pk>`, you need to use a RegEx:

```
url("article/([0-9]+)/", ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name="article-detail")
```

Note that this will be deprecated in the future and if you are using django >=2.0 you should use [`path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urls/#django.urls.path):

```
path("article/<int:article>/", ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name="article-detail")
```

However this will still direct you to the wrong view. django stops after the first URL pattern match.

Switch them around to fix that:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url("article/([0-9]+)/", ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name="article-detail"),
    # path("article/<int:article>/", ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name="article-detail"),  # alternative with path instead of url
    url('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to this line

```py
url('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
```

Because `url` wraps `re_path` there may be some logic which will treat the blank regex string as a wildcard. Try changing it to `'/'`

```py
url('/', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
```